# Alamofire doesnt allow to send object directly

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

My API only accepts object as the body , but alamofire only sends Dictionary as an object, which my server is not accepting requesting help

I have to call an API which is a post api using alamofire

as soon as i convert the model to dictionary and dicitionary to json 
and post it Alamofire does not allow me to post a string

it allows me to send a dictionary which my api does not accept

```
["key":"value"]- Not acceptable
{"key":"value"}- Acceptable
```

Can anyone share any solution?

I am using Swift 5 , Xcode 10, Alamofire 4.8.2

```
do{
    let d  = try data.asDictionary()
    jsonString = DictionaryToJSON(data: dictionary)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: jsonString, encoding: .utf8, headers: [: ]).responseJSON { (res) in
    print(res.result)
    print("Request Data \(res.request) \n Dictionary \(jsonString)")
    do {
        let d = try JSONDecoder().decode([OTPMessage].self, from: res.data!)
        print(d[0].message)
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}

// Dictionary to JSON

func DictionaryToJSON(data: [String:Any])->String {
    if let theJSONData = try? JSONSerialization.data(
        withJSONObject: data,
        options: .prettyPrinted
    ),
    let theJSONText = String(data: theJSONData, encoding: String.Encoding.ascii) {
        print("JSON string = \n\(theJSONText)")
        return theJSONText
    }
    else {
        return ""
    }
}

// Object to Dictionary

extension Encodable {
    func asDictionary() throws -> [String: Any] {
        let data = try JSONEncoder().encode(self)
        guard let dictionary = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments) as? [String: Any] else {
            throw NSError()
        }
        return dictionary
    }
}

//Struct
struct OTPMessage:Codable {
    var message = String()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to convert your dictionary to a JSON String because `Alamofire` can do the encoding, see this [example](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Usage.md#json-encoding).

I suggest you to change your code to something like this

```
do{
   let dictionary = try data.asDictionary()
   Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: dictionary, encoding: .JSON, headers: [:]).responseJSON { (res) in
        print(res.result)
        print("Request Data \(res.request) \n Dictionary \(jsonString)")
        do{
            let d = try JSONDecoder().decode([OTPMessage].self, from: res.data!)
            print(d[0].message)
        }catch{
            print(error)
        }
    }
} catch{
    print(error)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With Alamofire you can not do this. What you need to do is creating a `URLRequest` object and setting the `httpBody` property of it and then passing it to Alamofire.

`URLRequest` allows you to have `Data` as POST body.

```
            var request = URLRequest(url: urlFinal)
            request.httpMethod = HTTPMethod.post.rawValue
            request.allHTTPHeaderFields = dictHeader
            request.timeoutInterval = 10
            request.httpBody = newPassword.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

            Alamofire.request(request).responseString { (response) in
                if response.response!.statusCode >= 200 && response.response!.statusCode <= 300 {
                    completion("success")
                }else {
                    completion("failed")
                }
            }
```

here `newPassword` is string. from there I created the `Data` object. You have to convert your Custom class object to `Data` object.